# Cannot unset a GET parameter unless location.reload is called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two php files named student_profile.php and viewQuizAnswers.php.

In student_profile.php I have `<a>` tag that calls the modal in viewQuizAnswers.php and the value from student_profile.php jumps to viewQuizAnswers.php

Imagine that the code below is repeated 10 times with different values of qzid and stid:

```
<a href="../php/viewQuizAnswers.php?qzid='.$quizid[$cnt].'&stid='.$stid.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View</a>
```

In viewQuizAnswers.php

```
$studid = $_GET['stid'];
$qzid = $_GET['qzid'];
```

After I got the value and the query succeeded I unset the _GET at the end of a query

```
unset($_GET["stid"]);
unset($_GET["qzid"]);
?>
```

But when I click a different  tag, the previous values are still there and I cannot get the new values I need.

I cannot unsetthe `_GET['qzid']` and `_GET['stid']` unless I use `location.reload();` and if I used `location.reload` I do not need to `UNSET` anymore

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    location.reload();
})

//this code is in viewQuizAnswers.php
```

But I do not want to use location reload because there is a lot of data and it takes too much time to load.

Comment: When you click again on `<a>` then it sends same `$_GET` request again

Comment: Hard to understand what your problem is here. _“the previous value are still there and the new value I need I cannot get”_ - what do you even mean by “previous” and “new” values here? Un-setting something in $_GET in one script does of course not change anything about the HTML code you output in a totally different and independent script.

Comment: Why do you click `<a>` again?

Comment: It's quite impossible to understand where you using what code... The way you are mixing PHP, HTML and javascript code throughout your files is messy. I suggest you to read a little bit more PHP and javascript tutorials.

Comment: @ZainFarooq because each <a> have different value of qzid and that value I will use for the query ( SELECT * from table where col = $variable(qzid) )

Comment: You have the problem in a flow of your code. I think you should upload your full code

Comment: I wonder if because you're binding the `<a` to a bootstrap modal, the bootstrap Javascript overrides the normal functionality of the link, and therefore it just opens the modal within the same page, rather than navigating to the new URL specified in the `<href`. Hence it never reloads the page, so it never requests anything new from the server, it never re-runs the query and the URL in the browser bar does not change. Your link can _either_ open a modal popup _or_ navigate to a new URL (which would cause the page to reload). It can't do both at the same time.

Comment: P.S. `unset($_GET["stid"]);
unset($_GET["qzid"]);` at the end of your script achieves nothing useful. Since the script is about to end anyway, all the variables will die at that point. Next time someone makes a request to that same PHP script, it starts again from the beginning as if it had never been run before. This is because HTTP and web applications are _stateless_.

Comment: Have you perhaps also got some other code which populates your modal popup? Maybe some Javascript making an AJAX request to another PHP script on the server? That might be a relevant part of the scenario. I don't know, it's hard to tell because we don't know for sure what the exact flow is what you want it to achieve. Do you want to load a modal popup, or do you want to do a full navigation to a new URL?